# 'if' coming at the end of a sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Is it OK to use *if* at the end of a sentence as opposed to the beginning? For example, are these expressions correct:

> The weather is good **if**, we can play tennis.

And this sentence:

> I will play tennis hopefully the weather is good **if**.

Comment: There are idioms which, if stretched to the limit, might allow "if" to be placed at the end of a sentence, but the above examples aren't even close -- they're virtually meaningless.

Comment: "Your If is the only peacemaker; much virtue in If."--Touchstone in *[As You Like It* 5.4](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/asyoulikeit/asyoulikeit.5.4.html).

Comment: I see. Thanks. Actually I remember a professor's email having if at the end. I'm not saying it is "grammatically" correct, but more saying if it is even makes sense or informally it is possible to use.

Comment: That's a big if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the answer is no.  Though there are some unusual idioms which allow `if` at the end.

For instance: "As if!"--which is a skeptical response--suggesting disbelief that a thing someone describes will actually happen.

```
Garth: "In a fight between Bugs Bunny and Superman, Bugs Bunny would win."
Wayne: "Yeah, right!  As if!"
```

> I will play tennis hopefully the weather is good if.

This, however, is wrong.

> The weather is good if, we can play tennis.

Without the comma, this is a legal sentence.  But it suggests something fairly bizarre, which is the idea that whether you play tennis or not is affecting the weather.  *(Or that somehow, people would be using whether your tennis match was canceled or not to tell what the weather was--so not causing the weather, but being used as an indicator.)*

You might find such a sentence in logic (or discussion of a logical fallacy):

```
We can play tennis if we find our rackets.
The weather is good if we can play tennis.
We found our rackets so the weather must be good.
```

A line of reasoning of that type might use this strange case of if.

Comment: _The weather is good if we can play tennis._ I would interpret that to mean "I consider the weather good if it's nice enough to play tennis." Put another way, "If it's not too windy, rainy, or cold for tennis, then it's a nice day." It's something an avid tennis enthusiast might say, but, as you point out, it's rather unusual. I think I'd be more inclined to say, "Any day nice enough for tennis is a great day," or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

## No

If is used as a conjunction, which holds the two parts of the sentence together. In order to do this, and because that is the way English works, it is placed at the beginning of the phrase.

If the weather is good, we can play tennis.

I will play tennis if the weather is good.